# slideToggle animates "show" but not "hide"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidetoggle

I have a website with 100% height that has a hidden footer, that needs to slide up and show it when a button is clicked, and when that button is clicked again, it should slide down and hide it.

The problem is that the sliding animation is only working when the footer slides up, and when it should slide down, it bumps without animation.

You can see the problem right [here](http://dev.stamina.pt/apoa/), by clicking on the "More" button in the footer.
The JS code used to manipulate that button is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".footer_container").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();    

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){

        var speed = "500";
        $(".footer_container").slideToggle(speed);

        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(document).height()
        }, speed);

    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** I just tried this code:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){

    var speed = "500";
    $(".footer_container").toggle(speed);

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".footer_container").offset().top + $('window').height()
    }, speed);

});
```

And aparently there's an animation going on the footer that I didn't know exist. Maybe that's the cause of this problem?

Comment: the link you given is working fine it is hiding again

Comment: It's working fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: @KeesSonnema, do you have animation on hide?

Comment: It's hiding it now, yeah (I updated my question above), but now there's an extra animation sliding the footer to the left that must've been there before, and now I can't find it.

Comment: And the reason there's no animation on "hide" is probably because that slide-left effect has always been there. Now I'm trying to figure out how I can remove it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright so i gave this a shot:

```
$('.show_hide').unbind()
$('.show_hide').click(function () {
    var speed = "500";
    $(".footer_container").toggle(speed);

    if ($(".footer_container").data('can-see')) {
        var displaced = $('.footer_container').height();
        $('.twitter_footer').animate({
            marginTop: "600px",
        }, {
            duration: speed,
            complete: function () {
                $('.twitter_footer').css('margin-top', "0");
            }
        });
    }

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".footer_container").offset().top + $('window').height()
    }, speed);

    $(".footer_container").data('can-see', !$(".footer_container").data('can-see'))

});
```

demonstration at http://jsfiddle.net/DPq5Z/

same result, another way (using absolute positioning in order to keep elements above undisturbed):

```
$('.show_hide').unbind()
$('.show_hide').click(function () {
    var speed = "500";
    $(".footer_container").fadeToggle(speed);

    if ($(".footer_container").data('can-see')) {
        slide_down('.twitter_footer', speed);
        slide_down('.button_bg', speed);

    }

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".footer_container").offset().top + $('window').height()
    }, speed);

    $(".footer_container").data('can-see', !$(".footer_container").data('can-see'))

});

function slide_down(c, speed){
    var tp = $(c).offset().top;
        $(c).css({
            'position': 'absolute',
                'top': tp + "px"
        });
        $(c).animate({
            top: tp + 170 + "px",
        }, {
            duration: speed,
            complete: function () {
                $(c).css({
                    'position': "relative",
                     'top': '0'  
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

demonstration at http://jsfiddle.net/9R6L4/

Comment: This is great! Never thought it would need so much code for such a simple effect!
I changed `$(".footer_container").toggle(speed);` with `$(".footer_container").fadeToggle(speed);` and it's working beautifully.

Comment: I just noticed a minor problem: on the [Food](http://dev.digicooltest.com/apoa/food/) page, when the footer is hiddden, the content also scrolls up. Any chance you can have a look at this?

Comment: Ended up making the content bit a fixed container, that'll do for now :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works as how default animations in jQuery work. If you want to customize this. You need to use jQuery easing plugin. It takes as parameter the easing effect, like easeIn, easeOut, Bounce etc.. that controls the flow. By default it is linear and that is what you see.

Easing Plugin: https://github.com/gdsmith/jquery.easing

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){

    var speed = "500";
    $(".footer_container").fadeToggle(speed);

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".footer_container").offset().top + $('window').height()
    }, speed);

});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vvmYH/4/

Comment: But it's animating on the slideUp, not on the slideDown. I updated my question with a different code that revealed there's another animation occuring on the footer and that maybe that's what's causing the issue. Did you get to check that out?

Comment: check my updated code and fiddle.. I just used fadeToggle Instead.

Comment: Okay, I just noticed your jsFiddle. What you did was add fading, but that's not what I'm trying to accomplish. Perhaps I didn't explain myself properly, apologies for that.

After you click "More" once, it slides up (with animation). But if you click again to slide down, it has no slide animation.

Comment: That's what I said in my answer, you need to use easing plugin for that, Read http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: I just checked that link and I don't need to use the easing plugin because the default animation is enough. It **is** animating, but only when it slides up. If the problem was the easing, it wouldn't work up.